Error React useEffect y useState: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop
Estoy usando useEffect para setear los valores que me da una api de unas fechas de cierre a un useState, pero al hacer setFechas Cierre este manda el error de ciclo infinito, pero no entiendo por qué.
Me da el siguiente error:

Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.

¿Así no es como se debe setear ese tipo de situaciones? he probado con ponerle lista de dependecias de los hooks del que depende el useEffect pero nada. He usado eslint pero no me da error alguno, no tengo idea de que poder hacer.

import React, {useState, useEffect, useContext} from 'react'
import Image from 'next/image'
import imagen from "@/app/Componentes/Imágenes/images.jpg"
import "./Contratacion.scss"
import Overlay from "./Componentes/modal"
import { now } from 'next-auth/client/_utils'
import { promises } from 'dns'

const Page = () => {

  interface Licitaciones {
    name: string
    id: number
    items: []
    EsCarpeta: boolean
    path: string
  }

  interface RegistrosFechas {
    id: number,
    Fecha: string,
    Nombre: string
  }

  const [Finished, setFinished] = useState<boolean>(false)
  const [Estadocerrados, setCerrados] = useState<boolean[]>([])
  const [Closed, setClosed] = useState<string[]>([""])
  const [FechasCierre, setFechasCierre] = useState<Record<string, Date>>({})

  const isClosed = (Foldername: string) => {
    if(Closed?.includes(Foldername)){
        return true
    }
    else{
        return false
    }

}

const HandleCloseds = (Foldername: string) => {
    setClosed((prev) => {
        const newarray = [...prev, Foldername]
        return newarray
    });
}    
  
  const HandleClick = (índice: number) => {
      setCerrados(prevState => {
        const Nuevosestados = [...prevState]
        Nuevosestados[índice] = !Nuevosestados[índice]
        return Nuevosestados
      });
  }

  const [Licitaciones, setLic] = useState<Licitaciones[]>([])

  

  const cambiarfecha = (fecha:Record<string, Date>  ) => {
    setFechasCierre(fecha)
  }

  useEffect(() => {

    

    async function ObtenerLic(){
      const response = await fetch('/api/Secretaria');
        const data = await response.json();
        console.log(data);
        const fecha: Record<string, Date> = {}
        if(data) {
         

          const ResetArray = Array(data.length).fill(false)
          
          
          setLic(data);
          setCerrados(ResetArray)

      
          
          
          
          
        } 
        
    }

    ObtenerLic()
    
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    ObtenerFechaCierre()
  }, [])

  const ObtenerFechaCierre = async() => {
    
      
      try{
        const response = await fetch('/api/Secretaria/Fechas/Consultar');
        const data = await response.json();
  
        if(data){
          console.log("LA fecha essss: ", data.registro)
          const fechaMap: Record<string, Date> = {} 
          await Promise.all(data.registro.map((registro: RegistrosFechas) => {
            fechaMap[registro.Nombre] = new Date(registro.Fecha)
          }))
          setFechasCierre(fechaMap)
          console.log("pureba registros: ", fechaMap)
        }else{
          console.log("No hay registro esperado")
          return null
        }
      }
      catch(err){
        console.log("error en la llamada a la api", err)
        return null;
      }

  }


  const ObtenerValoresIniciales = (lic: Licitaciones) => {
      let Downloads: string[] = [] 
      lic.items.forEach((element: Licitaciones) => {
        if(!element.EsCarpeta)
        {
          Downloads = [...Downloads, element.name]
        }
      })

      return {Downloads}
  }


  return (
   <main> 
    <section className='contenedor-contratacion'>{

    Licitaciones.map((lic) => {
      let Fechacierre = FechasCierre[lic.name]
      let FechaCierreDate = new Date(Fechacierre);
      let FechaActual = new Date()
      let index = lic.id
      let InitialPath = lic.path
      const {Downloads} = ObtenerValoresIniciales(lic) 

      if(FechaActual > FechaCierreDate){
        HandleCloseds(lic.name)
      }

      return (<>
        <span className='boton-contratacion' onClick={() => {HandleClick(index);}}>
          {lic.name}
        </span>

        <Overlay isClosed={isClosed} FolderPath={InitialPath} InitFilename={Downloads} Name={lic.name} Finished={Finished}  cerrado={Estadocerrados[index]} HandleClick={() => HandleClick(index)}/>
      </>
      )
    })
      

    }   
    </section>

    
   </main> 
  )
}

export default Page



Si en useEffect usas de trigger un state que modificas en el propio effect, tienes un bucle infinito puesto que cada vez que se ejecute el effect se actualizará el state y esa actualización disparará otra vez el effect... y así hasta el infinito. Asegúrate de no añadir cosas a lo loco a tu useEffect :)

Realmente al principio no tenia ninguna dependecia en el useEffect, es decir, estaba así: UseEffect(() => {}, []), eso se lo agregue luego para ver si se arreglaba, no se mucho de React aún

El problema principal es llamar a HandleCloseds durante el renderizado causa un bucle infinito de renderizado.
Como solución te sugiero, mueve la lógica a un useEffect que depende de Licitaciones y FechasCierre.
Como corrección adicional, asegúrate de que las funciones ObtenerFechaCierre y ObtenerLic se llamen solo cuando sea necesario, evitando bucles innecesarios o múltiples llamadas. Aplicando estas correcciones deberías resolver el error de demasiadas re-renderizaciones
